# Mysql version install with shell script

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, vagrant

I started working on this shell script for my virtual environment.
I use ubuntu 14.04 and default MySQL version is 5.5.
I need MySQL 5.7 installed, I don't know how and if its possible to install that version on ubuntu 14.04, here is what I started working on, I was wondering if you could help me modify this to get it working the right way

```
#install services and apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y joe acl git

sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password vagrant'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password vagrant'
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get -y install unzip

#install apache
sudo apt-get install -y apache2

#install php 7
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0-mysql
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0-mcrypt
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0-mbstring
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0-memcache
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0-xmlrpc
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0-xsl
sudo apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-php7.0
sudo apt-get -y install language-pack-UTF-8
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0-curl
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0-gd


#set virtualhost file to sites-available and enable site
sudo cp -rf /var/www/vagrant-dependencies/vagrant.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo apachectl restart

#create DB
sudo mysql -u root -pvagrant -e "CREATE DATABASE vagrant"
```

Comment: *"I was wondering if you could help me modify this to get it working the right way"* - You need to clearly state what is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Install the MySQL APT Repository by downloading:

```
https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

and running:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

during the installation, you will be asked to choose the versions of the MySQL server then update the package database with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install MySQL server with:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

You can also look at the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/).

Comment: Yes but that is with terminal. Im running the script, how to select the version with sh script?